# SQL: GROUP BY with individual group filter from subquery

Tags: sql, filter, group-by, subquery

I have below query that cross joins Person_ID from Persons table and Date Range from DateRange. Which gives me a Person_ID for each date in the range.

```
WITH DateRange(DateData) AS
                    (
                        SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '02/01/2016') as Date
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT DATEADD(d,1,DateData)
                        FROM DateRange
                        WHERE DateData < CONVERT(DATETIME, '04/26/2016')
                    )
SELECT TBL_PERSONS.ID AS PERSON_ID, DateRange.DateData AS [DATE]
       FROM
         TBL_PERSONS
         CROSS JOIN DateRange                                    
         WHERE TBL_PERSONS.STATUS='Active'
```

Now what I am trying to do is for each Person_ID I want to filter the rows upto max date from a different table for the same Person_ID. Something like this,

```
WITH DateRange(DateData) AS
                    (
                        SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '02/01/2016') as Date
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT DATEADD(d,1,DateData)
                        FROM DateRange
                        WHERE DateData < CONVERT(DATETIME, '02/15/2016')
                    )
SELECT T1.PERSON_ID, T1.[DATE]
FROM 
    (SELECT TBL_PERSONS.ID AS PERSON_ID, DateRange.DateData AS [DATE]
       FROM
         TBL_PERSONS
         CROSS JOIN DateRange                                    
         WHERE TBL_PERSONS.STATUS='Active'
     ) T1
GROUP BY T1.PERSON_ID, T1.[DATE]
HAVING T1.[DATE] <=  (SELECT DATEADD(day, 5, MAX(CAST(event_time_Local AS DATE))) AS [DATE] 
                                    FROM TBL_EVENTS_HISTORY
                                    WHERE PRIMARYID = T1.PERSON_ID
                                    GROUP BY PRIMARYID )
```

But this still gives all date for all person_id. I tried using Where instead of HAVING but nothing changes. Also I tried, below but again the same result.

```
WITH DateRange(DateData) AS
                    (
                        SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '02/01/2016') as Date
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT DATEADD(d,1,DateData)
                        FROM DateRange
                        WHERE DateData < CONVERT(DATETIME, '02/15/2016')
                    )
SELECT T1.PERSON_ID, T1.[DATE]
FROM 
    (SELECT TBL_PERSONS.ID AS PERSON_ID, DateRange.DateData AS [DATE]
       FROM
         TBL_PERSONS
         CROSS JOIN DateRange                                    
         WHERE TBL_PERSONS.STATUS='Active'
     ) T1
JOIN 
(SELECT PRIMARYID AS PERSON_ID, DATEADD(day, 5, MAX(CAST(event_time_Local AS DATE))) AS [DATE] 
                                    FROM TBL_EVENTS_HISTORY
                                    GROUP BY PRIMARYID ) T2
ON T1.PERSON_ID = T2.PERSON_ID
AND T1.[DATE] <= T2.[DATE]
```

My question, is am I doing something wrong? or is it even possible to have seperate filter for each group?

Note: I am trying to build query that is independent of SQL server or Oracle.

Comment: can you post your data and table structure and expected result thanks

Comment: It looks like a `LATERAL JOIN` would be useful here. It is in the SQL standard, but different DBMS have different keywords for it. For example, in SQL Server it is called `CROSS/OUTER APPLY`. If you provide some sample data and expected result, most likely somebody will write a specific answer.